# Bash Script not deterministic in performing actions

Tags: shell-script

I have a bash script which I invoke on system boot (Ubuntu 10.04) "Startup Applications".

script:

```
#!/bin/sh

APP1='/home/ipc-display/development/projects/display-mgmt'
LOG='/home/ipc-display/development/projects/bootLog.txt'

cd $APP1/target/scala-2.10
java -jar display-mgmt-1.0.jar &

# Auto Hide Mouse Pointer
/usr/bin/unclutter &

#Start chrome
sleep 5s
/usr/bin/google-chrome --incognito --app=http://192.168.0.100:9000/welcome &

#Bring Chrome to focus
sleep 5s
/usr/bin/wmctrl -a "http://" && 

#FullScreen Chrome
sleep 3s &&
/usr/bin/xdotool key F11

bash
```

My HORRENDOUS scripting ability aside, any ideas on why Chrome does not ALWAYS deterministically go to full screen as I expect?

I am scratching my head not able to understand why it goes to full screen sometimes but not all the time. As an aside, any enhancements to this script would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess this has nothing to do with scripting. Is ensured that (a) Chrome is ready to process the input and (b) Chrome still has the focus when `xdotool` is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a timing issue may be causing this - maybe something is being foregrounded in the three seconds between focusing Chrome and pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>.

I'm not sure how `wmctrl` works, but it seems a bit incongruous that you use `&&` at the end of that line. That doesn't background the process, but rather instructs the shell to run the next command (`sleep 3s`) only if the command succeeds.

However, you can simply use `--kiosk` to fullscreen Chrome on startup and skip the rest of the script.

Comment: I read online about the --kiosk switch but it doesn't seem to work on the machine, it does not have an internet connection and the chrome version is at least 1 year old. I will try removeing the `sleep` and `&&` though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks fine, but I don't think you need to insert so many `sleep` invocations in it. People typically use `sleep` to get around race conditions brought on by being unable to determine the completion of some asynchronous task. For example, doing a `wget` to kick off remote script execution and waiting enough time for the server to generate a file they can do a follow up `GET` on, you'd probably use `sleep` to get around not knowing when that file is ready. It's kind of kludgy but it works for what most people need.

Your `sleep`'s here don't really make sense, though. For example, I don't think much harm will come if `chrome` starts up before `unclutter` has a chance to do its thing. There's also no asynchronous task that you're waiting to complete with `wmctl` (well there's IPC involved, but I don't think `wmctl` would return before the communication had already finished) so inserting three seconds of `sleep` seems excessive. I would think any amount of `sleep` would be unnecessary, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's your problem, but changing the active window is unreliable: something else might change the active window during your sleep. Instead you should tell `xdotool` to send the key to the desired window.

```
xdotool search --class Google-chrome -- key F11
```

[As l0b0 remarked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128288), you should probably use `google-chrome --kiosk …` instead.